How do I ask a question about a board game without a tag when I can't create tags?
I want to post a question about the Slay the Spire board game. However, no tag exists for the game and I don't have enough reputation to create the tag. What tag should I use when asking my question?

Post it with a tag such as house rules or identify this game but make sure it is clear what game you are asking about. If you do that someone who has the ability to make new tags will update the question with the new tags.
